# Code isn't working inside Function which is working outside

Tags: php

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

function getid()
{
    $fname = @$_POST['fname'];
    $lname = @$_POST['lname'];
    $email = @$_POST['email'];
    $password = @$_POST['password'];

    if (@$_POST['login'])
    {
        $qry = "insert into register values (NULL, '$fname', '$lname',   
        '$email', '$password')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $qry);  
    }
};
```

Calling of the function in another file where the html exists:

```
include 'Config\api.php';

getid($conn, $_POST);

getid();
```

Taking into consideration that the code is working outside of the function which means that the connection is working and there is no problem with the coding or variables. Thank you.

Comment: Add `global $conn` at the beginning of your function, if it is defined outside the function.

Comment: what error are you getting? You should pass an argument within your function as your attributes are empty getid($conn) and at the very last please remove the terminator why you are using the terminator at the end braces of your function block

Comment: Please, *please*, **please** read about SQL injection. It's **very** important, as this code is a security disaster.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I will look it up thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You funtion `getid()` cannot access the global variable `$conn`. You can make it accessible to the function defining it like this :

```
function getid()
{
  global $conn;
  //Now you can use it inside the function.
}
```

Or pass it as a variable when calling the function like this :

```
function getid($conn)
{
  //Now you can use $conn inside the function.
}

//Call the function like this 
getid($conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` is using in this function. You need to pass `$_POST` & `$conn` to function.

Change from

```
function getid()
```

to

```
function getid($conn, $_POST)
```

and then call it like `getid($conn, $_POST);`

Note: You must call this function where form is submitting.

Comment: I agree but ,$_POST is needed?

Comment: yes, I am calling in another file and it is working when i get it out of the function. I added $conn and $_POST the way you mentioned  in the function and in the calling of the function and still isnot work

Comment: are u telling you are calling a getid function which is in another file? have you included the file?

Comment: @hossam share your complete code.

Comment: `$_POST` is not needed to pass as parameter to a function. It is accessible to any function.

Comment: @hassaan the whole code is posted

Comment: @TareqMahmood yes it is a super global variable, it is supposed to be accessible to any function

Comment: @hossam, but your `$conn` is not like so.

Comment: @TareqMahmood I included the whole code, the $conn is global too you can check it

Comment: It's global but not superglobal as like `$_POST`. It cannot be accessed if it's not passed or defined as global inside the function.

Comment: @TareqMahmood it seems you were right, when I inserted the include function of the connection  inside the function it worked